# Git init initializes on different directory instead of the current

Tags: git

I think I have misconfigured something, When I do a `git init --bare` on `/git/math-site.com` in instead initializes the directory on an already existing git directory `/git/science-site.com`. Why does it initialize the repo on another directory?

Here's the list of commands I did:

```
cd /git/math-site.com
git init --bare
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /git/science-site.com/
```

Edit: I tried deleting `/git/science-site.com` and `/git/math-site.com` and now a new errors arises.

```
mkdir /git/math-site.com && cd /git/math-site.com
git init --bare
fatal: GIT_WORK_TREE (or --work-tree=<directory>) not allowed without specifying GIT_DIR (or --git-dir=<directory>)
```

Comment: Do you have the environment variable `GIT_DIR` set? (type `echo $GIT_DIR`)

Comment: @GregHewgill Yes it's set to `/git/science-site.com` I think you're getting closer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unset GIT_DIR`  and also `GIT_WORK_TREE` and try. Normally, you should not be manually setting that environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that /git/math-site.com is not a symlink of /git/science-site.com?

```
gil@machine:~/git:ruby-1.8.7:$ mkdir real-dir
gil@machine:~/git:ruby-1.8.7:$ ln -s real-dir symlink-dir
gil@machine:~/git:ruby-1.8.7:$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    4 gil  staff   136 30 Jul 13:34 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 106 gil  staff  3604 30 Jul 13:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 gil  staff    68 30 Jul 13:34 real-dir
lrwxr-xr-x    1 gil  staff     8 30 Jul 13:34 symlink-dir -> real-dir
gil@machine:~/git:ruby-1.8.7:$ cd symlink-dir
gil@machine:~/git/symlink-dir:ruby-1.8.7:$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/gil/git/real-dir/
```

Comment: I tried deleting the two directories, there are no symlinks. Please check my edit, thanks!